# Streaming content to bluetooth speaker without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth Speaker which requires me to pair and then I am able to play music on it. Is it possible to play music on it without pairing when it is idle(when it is not paired with any device) or pairing with multiple bluetooth speakers/devices at once. I want to create an Android app for that if its possible. I was unable to find any useful information on this so far.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is (or should be) possible. Bluetooth uses end-to-end encryption, which is partly negotiated during the pairing phase. If you ignore the pairing phase, this encryption would not be possible (or be completely insecure) and violate the bluetooth protocol.